# C++ send boost::dynamic_bitset with Winsock2 sendto function

Tags: c++, boost, winsock2, sendto

I am trying to send raw bits from a boost::dynamic_bitset with the Winsock2 sendto function.
MS documentation shows that sendto uses const char * type for the buffer parameter.
How do I send only the raw bits stored in the dynamic_bitset?  I don't know how to cast or manipulate the dynamic_bitset so that it can be used in the sendto function.

Here are some relevant lines from my program:

```
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <system_error>
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.hpp>
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
using boost::dynamic_bitset;

dynamic_bitset<> getDynamicBitset() {
    //code to return a dynamic_bitset here
}
//create a dynamic bitset from a function
dynamic_bitset<> db1 = getDynamicBitset(); 

//manipulation of dynamic_bitset needed here to make it work in sendto as the buffer parameter

int ret = sendto(sock, buffer, len, flags, reinterpret_cast<SOCKADDR*>(&address), sizeof(address));
```

I am using the sample code from Peter R here:
[How do I receive udp packets with winsock in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14665543/how-do-i-receive-udp-packets-with-winsock-in-c)

Also, my question is related to this, but I'm using C++ and not C.
[Sending a structure in the sendto() function - C language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26455284/sending-a-structure-in-the-sendto-function-c-language)

I'm new to C++ and barely understand pointers and type manipulation.

Thanks.

Comment: What structure will eventually the bits end up in on the other side?  Will it also be a boost dynamic_bitset?

Comment: I'm not sure, and maybe that's the problem.  Ultimately I want programs on the network that are listening for Protocol Data Units to receive and interpret them.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_data_unit - see SISO-REF-010-2020 and IEEE 1278.1-2012

Comment: You could send the data as a string of `0` and `1` characters if that meets the requirements.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie But why would you do that? That would take eight times the bandwidth

Comment: Since a dynamic bitset can be an unlimited number of bits, the other option would be to send the bits in maybe 32-bit or 64-bit chunks.  @OP -- This isn't really that much of a C++ issue -- the dynamic bitset has all of the functions needed to see if a particular bit is set.  It's just a matter of putting together an array that can be sent over the socket.  All C++ does is to make the access of each bit a convenient class member function.  A C program would look no different, except the function would probably be called "GetBit" or "IsBitSet".

Comment: @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes the smallest unit of data that a socket can send/receive is a byte, not a bit.  If the `dynamic_bitset` has fewer than 8 bits in it, you are going to waste bandwidth sending unused bits anyway. So you may as well convert your `dynamic_bitset` data into a portable format, such as a `uintX[]` array. You said yourself that you don't know if the other party is also using `dynamic_bitset`, so you can't just send the raw bitset data as-is anyway, it needs to be serialized to a form the other party can then deserialize into whatever it wants.

Comment: I've been thinking about how to explain the receiving end better - it will be Distributed Interactive Simulation protocol (DIS).  For reference, the packet size is variable, but 1,152 bits is typical.

Comment: @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes actually, 256x the bandwidth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've implemented serialization for dynamic_bitset before: [How to serialize boost::dynamic_bitset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31006792/how-to-serialize-boostdynamic-bitset/31015623#31015623)

You can use that or a similar technique based on the same interfaces:

```
template <typename Block, typename Alloc>
std::string to_binary_string(boost::dynamic_bitset<Block, Alloc> const& bs) {
    uint32_t const num_bits = bs.size();
    auto const num_blocks = div_roundup(num_bits, sizeof(Block)*CHAR_BIT);

    // prepare zeroed output buffer
    std::string buf(sizeof(num_bits) + num_blocks * sizeof(Block), '\0');

    // write size prefix 
    std::memcpy(buf.data(), &num_bits, sizeof(num_bits));

    // write block data
    if (num_bits > 0) { // mustn't pass nullptr to src argument of memcpy
        auto b = reinterpret_cast<Block*>(buf.data() + sizeof(num_bits));
        to_block_range(bs, b);
    }
    return buf;
}
```

Which you could send like:

```
std::string buf = to_binary_string(my_bitset);

int ret = sendto(sock, buf.data(), buf.size(), flags, reinterpret_cast<SOCKADDR*>(&address), sizeof(address));
```

The analogous deserialization code:

```
template <typename Block, typename Alloc>
void from_bytes(std::string_view buf, boost::dynamic_bitset<Block, Alloc>& bs) {
    // read the size prefix
    uint32_t num_bits;
    if (buf.size() < sizeof(num_bits)) {
        throw std::length_error("from_bytes");
    }
    std::memcpy(&num_bits, buf.data(), sizeof(num_bits));

    // shift buf to only cover the actual bit data
    buf = buf.substr(sizeof(num_bits));

    // read the bits as blocks
    bs.resize(num_bits);
    if (buf.size() % sizeof(Block) != 0) {
        throw std::length_error("from_bytes");
    }
    auto b = reinterpret_cast<Block const*>(buf.data());
    auto e = reinterpret_cast<Block const*>(buf.data() + buf.size());
    size_t const num_blocks = std::distance(b, e);
    
    // sanity checks block count vs num_bits
    if (num_blocks != div_roundup(num_bits, sizeof(Block)*CHAR_BIT)) {
        throw std::length_error("from_bytes"); // num_blocks doesn't match num_bits
    }

    from_block_range(b, e, bs);
    bs.resize(num_bits);
}
```

## Live Demo

> Disclaimer:
>
> - Portability is NOT addressed here. If you send data across systems using different native byte orderings, the behaviour is unspecified,
>   even though care has been taken to not BLOW UP, the data would be
>   wrong even in the extremely unlikely event that the sizes would add
>   up.
> - Similarly, no guarantees are made when the deserialized type doesn't *exactly* match the serialized type in terms of Block type.
>
> That aside, the program tests edge cases and runs clean under
> ASAN/UBSAN.

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1581ce6ae3a07b04)**

```
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp>
#include <climits>      // CHAR_BIT
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
// demo output
#include <iostream>

static inline size_t div_roundup(size_t p, size_t q) {
    // quick&dirty, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/926806/85371
    return (p+q-1)/q;
}

template <typename Block, typename Alloc>
std::string to_binary_string(boost::dynamic_bitset<Block, Alloc> const& bs) {
    uint32_t const num_bits = bs.size();
    auto const num_blocks = div_roundup(num_bits, sizeof(Block)*CHAR_BIT);

    // prepare zeroed output buffer
    std::string buf(sizeof(num_bits) + num_blocks * sizeof(Block), '\0');

    // write size prefix 
    std::memcpy(buf.data(), &num_bits, sizeof(num_bits));

    // write block data
    if (num_bits > 0) { // mustn't pass nullptr to src argument of memcpy
        auto b = reinterpret_cast<Block*>(buf.data() + sizeof(num_bits));
        to_block_range(bs, b);
    }
    return buf;
}

template <typename Block, typename Alloc>
void from_bytes(std::string_view buf, boost::dynamic_bitset<Block, Alloc>& bs) {
    // read the size prefix
    uint32_t num_bits;
    if (buf.size() < sizeof(num_bits)) {
        throw std::length_error("from_bytes");
    }
    std::memcpy(&num_bits, buf.data(), sizeof(num_bits));

    // shift buf to only cover the actual bit data
    buf = buf.substr(sizeof(num_bits));

    // read the bits as blocks
    bs.resize(num_bits);
    if (buf.size() % sizeof(Block) != 0) {
        throw std::length_error("from_bytes");
    }
    auto b = reinterpret_cast<Block const*>(buf.data());
    auto e = reinterpret_cast<Block const*>(buf.data() + buf.size());
    size_t const num_blocks = std::distance(b, e);
    
    // sanity checks block count vs num_bits
    if (num_blocks != div_roundup(num_bits, sizeof(Block)*CHAR_BIT)) {
        throw std::length_error("from_bytes"); // num_blocks doesn't match num_bits
    }

    from_block_range(b, e, bs);
    bs.resize(num_bits);
}

int main() {
    ::srand(::time(0)); // extremely lazy bad random, sue me

    for (auto bits = 0; bits < 128; ++bits) {
        boost::dynamic_bitset<> my_bitset(bits), roundtrip;

        for (size_t bit = 0; bit < my_bitset.size(); ++bit)
            my_bitset.set(bit, rand()%2);

        from_bytes(to_binary_string(my_bitset), roundtrip);

        std::cout << "{" << roundtrip << "} " << (roundtrip == my_bitset? "OK":"ERROR") << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Printing:

```
{} OK
{0} OK
{11} OK
{001} OK
{0010} OK
{01000} OK
{110011} OK
{0101011} OK
{01101101} OK
{101011011} OK
{1011100010} OK
{11100100110} OK
{110010010000} OK
{0011100110110} OK
{11100110110001} OK
{111101110011011} OK
{1011101100011011} OK
{10101000000110111} OK
{000000110100111111} OK
{0110001110100001011} OK
{11111111010010010110} OK
{010011100110111000011} OK
{0110011101111000111000} OK
{10011100110001001110101} OK
{011001001100011111010011} OK
{1101010010110100000100101} OK
{01101111001100100010111110} OK
{010101111001011111100011000} OK
{0101111001111001000001011011} OK
{10011101100111110110110001010} OK
{000001110000100011000011101000} OK
{1101010001101101111001001110000} OK
{11111010100111110010101111110010} OK
{110010101001101110000001011101110} OK
{1010100100010000011011011010000111} OK
{11101101111011011010110101101010000} OK
{110000101010100111010111011110100010} OK
{1000111110000001111010110000001111010} OK
{00010010011001111101101110101111000000} OK
{000000011000001100101000111110000111101} OK
{1000111111000000000111101110111101100010} OK
{01001110000011011100111110100100010111011} OK
{001000011101111001110111110000110100011001} OK
{0011010001000110100101000010110000101101001} OK
{01110111010111101000011110110011011110110101} OK
{111001000011011110001100000111001000001101010} OK
{1110001101010100101110100111001010100111111001} OK
{00110110011111110001110111110101101010100000110} OK
{101000100110100111001000110111010101101011000011} OK
{0011111001111000011010110110111110111011001101000} OK
{00011100110101100011000001010000111001011001111111} OK
{100101100001101111011001000101110100111110000100001} OK
{1110101000000100001111100111101101111100100011111111} OK
{00001010100111101001000100010111101101100101000001110} OK
{110101000110000011000100000001100100111101001100110011} OK
{1001111110001011100010011110001011010111101010101100100} OK
{00101001010011101000100110011011110101100110000110100010} OK
{010101000111011001001010011001010110111110101011001100100} OK
{0101100010000001010001110011001100000001011101101010110000} OK
{01000111001101100011000010010010111010010010111101101001010} OK
{000111101101111000011101101101101101100001011110111000001000} OK
{0111101011101011101000011001010000011001010111001001111000011} OK
{01000100010000000110001110110010110100001000001011110000010011} OK
{110100101010111101010010011100110000110100001010110100110001011} OK
{0111110001111011011001110000101100111011010000000101111010000111} OK
{01101000000101000000010010010100010101000110100011001010011011011} OK
{110111111011010011011001001011000100010000100001001000000111110011} OK
{0000111000100111101000000001111000011100000101010100001101111101111} OK
{11100101011110110110101100100100110110110110000000000101000000000011} OK
{111011000011111101100101001010010010101110001001100110111100101011101} OK
{1001110011100111010010110011010111111001100110010011010100101000010010} OK
{01011111001100011100000000011100000111010111001111100001100110001111110} OK
{010010111000101000111100000000010011111110010110011110000000000000001100} OK
{1101010011010110010100000100100110100100100110011100011010000001000001011} OK
{10100101001110110001011010010101100100110100011011001000010110100001101010} OK
{101010100011101100111000111001011011010111000101101011111011000001010111110} OK
{1011011101011011000101101101000110011001001001110101010010001010111000101011} OK
{01100101111100011110101000001010111101011011100101111000101110011011110011100} OK
{111100111010011100010111101010110101110000100111011001001111001100001011111110} OK
{0000010110001101001001110010011011010111100010100001111010100000100000101010010} OK
{10010100010000110101000000101001011011001001000110110110110001000001001000011011} OK
{011011101100001101001110111110000111010111010011001100100010011111110000101101000} OK
{0011001100110110111111101010011111010001000001110001010000101110111100100010111101} OK
{10001101001110001000001110110011111010010111100101011100111110010100010111100001010} OK
{111100011111110011011001001111101111110001010100010000001101000000101001111110011000} OK
{1001100110101000000110001000101010100101110100011100100010111111010101101001110000011} OK
{11000111100001000001001010010011010101100100101100001100101110010100000000000111100000} OK
{011011101010011001000000101101100011010110001000111010100001111000111001101011110111110} OK
{1011100111101110001111011101111010011100111111111110011010010000111101100000110111110000} OK
{11010010100011011010011111101011100101010100110100101001010011100011100001001000010001100} OK
{101100101110110110010010010001000010101100101010000110000100101111110100010111010111010000} OK
{1001100111111100000101011010100111101010000110010100100111011001010101111010100000000110011} OK
{11001000001101011000100011101111000001110011000100010011011011110010110001111001000101000010} OK
{010101110110011011001001111010100001101010110101001101010100110111011101001110111011111111001} OK
{0000001100010100101010000011000000100110011001011111101110100111011110100011011101001011001111} OK
{11101001010111000101001110011001010000000110010110011010100001000010011010010010010110110110100} OK
{100001001010100100000100111100101100000111111010110010101101000110010110010110011111110010111010} OK
{0110011101101011110011100101100110111110011110110001100101011000101110110001011110100000001010101} OK
{11111011101101010010010000101110000111011011001010001000000111101110110001000101110100110101001100} OK
{101001001001010101110010000100001000001101111111010000000110100111110001111010100100001001100100100} OK
{1010011111100001100101101110111001110011110100000100100100110011101110001000010000100001011101001101} OK
{10101011111010101101011101110010101111010001100011111000110011111011101110101110011011010111110011010} OK
{101001011011011011111101011110110000010001000011001011111100011000001100111100001000101111101000110100} OK
{1100001111000101010001010010000110011001111111011101100011111010100011110011011001001110010100111101010} OK
{01110111101110010010110110011011100101001010011010110010000011100111111101010110110001000111101011001011} OK
{111110001010000011111101001011100010111001001110001101001011100010111001011001111110001110111000010001010} OK
{1000110001111101001001100010011101011011000000001010111001111001100001001000101111001011010000011100100110} OK
{01101100101011110001001001101001110100111100111101000100010111101011000101101110101011010100011111110101111} OK
{100011010110010100001100010011111100101010011010110101001010000100011100011110000110111101000011011110010111} OK
{0001110100111110010010100101000111111101101110010011100110111101111001111111100101100000101110011011000001101} OK
{10000101011100100101100111111000010100011100010101111000001101010011111010011011011000110011000100110100101000} OK
{100110110011000000010000100011100010010101110000111010010101011000110101111101110011011101001011001101010001010} OK
{1001010100011011000111111111111001011010000001110100011100001101000001000010101000111110110010100101101111111111} OK
{00111000110111101110100111000110101111111101101100011111111110101010101001000000110000111101101111010011100011011} OK
{111100000100010001011010111001111111010111001101000100010011010110100111011010111101001110010001001111100110110010} OK
{1111110110110111110000001110010010100011000101001001111010001001111101111100000011000101001001001101000110000001100} OK
{11110101001111001100101001010100101110100011000101110001101101101110111101010101111011010100000110100011111011010101} OK
{100111000001000011100001011000001100100010101011110110001100010100001011111011000011100110011001101110011111101000101} OK
{1110110110010100001000101001001110100000110010110011110001111111110011111010000010111101001000110010011111001111101000} OK
{00000101100100000111110000100101010100101000011000111010110110111100111101111110110101100011101101011000000001001110111} OK
{010111011011000010001010010100010110001001101101101101001011010001000010010000000111011100100110101011001000001011011000} OK
{0011011110010110010111101101111100111110000010111101010001101111101101101001001000101101101001110000110000000110100010010} OK
{00001001010011101011011010010000000011000110011100000101111000100101111110101111100100011110100101011101101111100011100101} OK
{001011011110110000011010101000001001100100011001000100110100100111100101100010111101001010101100100100011010111010000101100} OK
{1111110110100111101011110100111011000001001111111010100011110001100100010010110110111110111100001011101000000100100000100100} OK
{01110000101110010101010110100001010010101010001111110100010111000011101000111010101111001011100111000011111011110011101011100} OK
{001100001010111010111001111011011000100100110010110001010000001110000001000110010101101000111110010101001010101100010111100011} OK
{1100011010110110001110101000110011110110010011010101110001010111110010000110011111110101111010110001010100110010000101001110011} OK
```

Comment: Found some more time to do the whole exercise properly ([Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1581ce6ae3a07b04)). Now it serializes the size as well as the bit data in binary form. See answer text for disclaimer.